# Android: Hiding or destroy view when onPause() is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-keyboard

Hi am using a customkeyboard view in my fragment. when ever user taps on the edit text am shwoing this view

```
insideEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    mKeyboardViewTolerance = new CustomKeyboard(getActivity(), R.id.keyboardviewtolerance, R.xml.keyboard_layout);
                    mKeyboardViewTolerance.showCustomKeyboard(insideEdit);
                    insideEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

when ever user switches to other fragments and comes to the same fragment and  taps the edittext the view is not rendering. I can see the view is there but the view is not visible on screen.

I tried hiding it in OnPause() but still the view is not visible

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
         if(mKeyboardViewTolerance != null && mKeyboardViewTolerance.isCustomKeyboardVisible()){

                mKeyboardViewTolerance.hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using focus listener on EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it will solve your problem:

```
 View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
 if (view != null) {
   InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: already using same in my showkeyboard()  wen tapping the edittext ...... public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
  mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
 
  if (v != null)
   ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity
     .getSystemService(mHostActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
     .hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
 }

Comment: can share import package name for your custom keyboard class

Comment: package com.ts.in.android.oring.activity;

Comment: its your custom package right?

use  Translate Animation for keyboard hiding.